# My canvas draw pixelated line

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to draw a little chart using some JavaScript and the canvas.

I'm doing a stuff like that :

```
RadarChart.prototype.fillRadar = function () {
var nbLabel = this.data.labels.length;
this.context.save();
this.context.lineWidth = 0.5;
this.context.lineJoin = "round";
this.context.translate(this.canvas.width / 2, this.canvas.height / 2);
this.context.strokeStyle = this.data.lineColor;
for (var i = 0; i < nbLabel; i++) {
    this.context.moveTo(0, 0);
    this.context.lineTo(0, -((this.canvas.height / 2) - 30))
    this.context.stroke();
    this.context.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * (360 / nbLabel));
}
this.context.restore();
}
```

the problem is that my lines are so pixelated and are not perfect. their width seems to change. It's like it's fading out over time...

[image: http://i.imgur.com/MVhHEru.png]

Why is it doing that? How can I fix it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why do you use `rotate` method? Why not calculate all end points and draw lines (rays) directly?

Comment: If you zoom in 4x on any bitmap image its going to be pixelated. Canvas is not SVG.

Comment: @ericjbasti I don't zoom. i'm at 100% and i just draw line.

Comment: @hindmost booth are options, i find rotating easier. I do'nt think the problem come from here, but if it's one of the reason i can change ^^

Comment: I get that. I'm thinking you're expectations may be unrealistic for how canvas draws lines. It's hard to tell without seeing a live example. The only time I've had an issue with pixelation (that wasn't expected) was from drawing a line without clearing the canvas first. If you draw a line in the same location without clearing it will get super pixelated after a couple draws (but that goes for everything).

Comment: I draw only one time. I will do a little fiddle to show you.

Comment: are you on a HDPI screen (mac book pro?, imac 5k)?

Comment: nope normal screen normal, windows 8.

Comment: Well you can always up the DPI of the canvas and see if that helps you. I gave an example for how to do that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395076/canvas-generated-by-canvg-is-blurry-on-retina-screen/24399725#24399725 Hope that helps.

Comment: Have you considered rendering using SVG instead of canvas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't set the width / height of the canvas using css

use 
`canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;`

make a function that find out how much 20% of the screen represent in pixel and then set the width/height in the code.